# How to change the search algorithm for Semantic UI dropdowns?

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I want to adapt the search algorithm in Semantic UI Dropdowns. It only matches items that start with the search text, but I want to match all items that contain the search text. Is it possible to add a custom search?

```
<select class="ui search selection dropdown">...</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can initialize the dropdown with the `fullTextSearch` option set to `true` to fuzzy match text anywhere in the string or `'exact'` to exactly match text anywhere in the string.

```js
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({ fullTextSearch: true });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui search selection dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="animal">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Select...</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="0">Cat</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="1">Horse</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="2">Seahorse</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="3">Wildcat</div>
  </div>
</div>
```